# Problems with extra spaces between two labels tkinter-python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I don't know why i have thoose spaces between the labels in the part 'Date'. I think it's a problem of the sizing of the Frame in which I have the labels, but there has to be a way to accommodate everything more stuck.
I put a message in the part of the code that is the problem.

I think that I have tried everything... It's my first time using tkinter. Thank you in advance for your help

```
from tkinter import *


# ======================== Window
window = Tk()
window.title("School Management System")
window.geometry("1350x750+0+0")


# ===================== Frames
top_frame = Frame(window, width=1000,height=100, bd=15, relief='raise')
top_frame.pack(side=TOP)

frames_L = Frame(window,  bd=5, width=100, relief='raise')
frames_L.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

frames_R = Frame(window, bd=5, relief='raise')
frames_R.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)


# ================= Labels =========================================
tittle = Label(top_frame, text="Lucille Rupp's School Management System",
                  font=('times new roman', 30, 'bold'), justify='center', width=30).grid(row=0, column=0)
# NAME
name_input = StringVar()
label_name = Label(frames_L, text=' First Name:', font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), justify='center', width=10)
label_name.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
entry_name = Entry(frames_L, font=('arial', 12), justify='left', width=30, relief='sunken', textvariable=name_input)
entry_name.grid(row=1, column=1)

#LAST NAME
lastname_input = StringVar()
label_lastname = Label(frames_L, text=' Last Name:', font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), justify='center', width=10)
label_lastname.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
entry_lastname = Entry(frames_L, font=('arial', 12), justify='left', width=30, relief='sunken', textvariable=lastname_input)
entry_lastname.grid(row=2, column=1)



#DATE ===== HERE IS THE PROBLEM =========

label_date = Label(frames_L, text='Date:', font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), width=10, anchor='w')
label_date.grid(row=3, column=0)

entry_day = Entry(frames_L,  font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),  width=10)
entry_day.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')

entry_month = Entry(frames_L,  font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),  width=10)
entry_month.grid(row=3, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to fit the two dates and you want First and Last names to end at same x, you should make those entryboxes for 2 columnspan, That will solve things for you.

```
from Tkinter import *


# ======================== Window
window = Tk()
window.title("School Management System")
window.geometry("1350x750+0+0")


# ===================== Frames
top_frame = Frame(window, width=1000,height=100, bd=15, relief='raise')
top_frame.pack(side=TOP)

frames_L = Frame(window,  bd=5, width=100, relief='raise')
frames_L.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

frames_R = Frame(window, bd=5, relief='raise')
frames_R.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)


# ================= Labels =========================================
tittle = Label(top_frame, text="Lucille Rupp's School Management System",
                  font=('times new roman', 30, 'bold'), justify='center', width=30).grid(row=0, column=0)
# NAME
name_input = StringVar()
label_name = Label(frames_L, text=' First Name:', font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), justify='center', width=10, anchor='w')
label_name.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
entry_name = Entry(frames_L, font=('arial', 12), justify='left', width=30, relief='sunken', textvariable=name_input)
entry_name.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)## Added Column Span

#LAST NAME
lastname_input = StringVar()
label_lastname = Label(frames_L, text=' Last Name:', font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), justify='center', width=10,anchor='w')
label_lastname.grid(row=2,  column= 0 , sticky=W)
entry_lastname = Entry(frames_L, font=('arial', 12), justify='left', width=30, relief='sunken', textvariable=lastname_input)
entry_lastname.grid(row=2, column=1 ,columnspan = 2)## Added Column Span



#DATE ===== HERE IS THE PROBLEM =========

label_date = Label(frames_L, text=' Date:', font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), justify='center', width=10, anchor='w')
label_date.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

entry_day = Entry(frames_L,  font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),  width=10)
entry_day.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)

entry_month = Entry(frames_L,  font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),  width=10)
entry_month.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)

window.mainloop()
```

The resulting window looks like this - 
[image]